# How to Verify Google Recaptcha V3 Response with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, recaptcha

I have this function to execute Ajax POST request :

```
function ajaxPost(url, data, callback) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", url, true);
    req.addEventListener("load", function () {
        if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
            callback(req.responseText);
        } else {
            console.error(req.status + " " + req.statusText + " " + url);
        }
    });
    req.addEventListener("error", function () {
        console.error("Erreur réseau avec l'URL " + url);
    });
    req.send(data);
}
```

But with this code, the captcah is never checked :

```
grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('reCAPTCHA_site_key', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
        var data = new FormData();
        data.set('g-recaptcha-response',token);
        ajaxPost("url", data, function(response){
            return response;
        });
    });
});
```

The script execute `ajaxPost()` BEFORE `grecaptcha.execute()`.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you need the callback for? You're already assigning a listener to "load". I think you can directly return req.responseText in that listener.
Just a guess..